# User not logged first time I open the homepage

Tags: login, homepage, session

I am experiencing a weird issue and I didn't find any luck on Google.

Every time I open my homepage it looks like I am not logged in (there is the form to login). But if I click on any internal link or menu option from the homepage, it comes out I am logged (and from that moment on I am correctly recognized as logged).

If I open the browser and point directly to an internal page I am recognized as logged.

Only if the first page I open is the homepage, my session is not recognized. Sometimes refreshing is enough to have me logged in the homepage, but sometimes I can press F5 ad libitum without getting me logged there.

I activated the debug and I don't get any error i the homepage. Anything else I can check?

The author of the template cannot support me as this issue doesn't happen on the demo website of the template.

Thanks in advance for your precious support!

Cheers

**UPDATE**: I made a quick test and it turned out that `is_user_logged_in()` is always false in the homepage... what could be the reason for that? :-o

Comment: Do you use a caching plugin or does your hosting provider use caching?

Comment: try disabling all plugins and switch to default theme and check if the problem still there.

Comment: I disabled all the plugins and turned to Twenty Twelve: the issue is still there: if I open any internal page I am logged, if the first page I open is the homepage I am not logged (as long as I don't click on any internal page). :(

Answer (score 0):

Just for everybody to know I finally got through this.

Wordpress was installed in a subfolder and the rewrite rule was partialy wrong, so that the session wasn't properly recognized from the homepage.

I rewrote the rule as it was suppsed to be and now everything works.